# How to enter number in Entry using button in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to add numbers (only 4 numbers) to entry via button in tkinter.
I tried  this code but it's not working. I need some suggestions.

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar()
var_entry = tk.Entry(win,text='var',textvariable=var)

def handle_button(event):
    return var.insert(0,4)

def window():
    global win
    var_entry.grid(row =1 ,column =2)

    button1 = tk.Button(win,text = '1' ,textvariable = 1)
    button1.bind("<Button-1>", handle_button)
    button1.grid(row = 2 , column = 0)
    # similarly I defined all the buttons.


windows()
win.mainloop()
```

The error it shows is:

> AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Does it mean "the code throws a `NameError: name 'windows' is not defined`"? Or does it mean "the code throws a `AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'insert'`"? Or something else?

Comment: error shows AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: Why do you think that `var` has an `insert` method? What do you think it means to insert into a variable? Did you try `var_entry.insert(0,4)`?

Comment: `StringVar()` uses `set()` to change the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the behavior you are looking for all you need to do is:

Change this:

```
def handle_button(event):
    return var.insert(0,4)
```

To this:

```
def handle_button(event):
    var.set(4)
```

That said there are a few things wrong with your code that are not useful here.

1. Looking at `return var.insert(0, 4)`. This `return` is actually not doing anything useful here because what it is trying to do is return the results of calling `var.insert(0, 4)` and assigning it to what ever called that function. 2 major problems with this. `var.insert(0, 4)` is not going to return a useful value for the return command to help and 2nd you cannot return a result to the binding it has no use. Instead delete the return all together and just write the command used to update the StringVar. In this case `var.set(4)`.
2. Looking at `var_entry = tk.Entry(win,text='var',textvariable=var)`. The `text = 'var'` is 100% useless here. In an entry field the argument `text` is actually short for `textvariable` so what is going on here is you are assigning the string `var` to the text variable and then immediately reassigning the textvariable to the StringVar(). So lets rewrite that line to just `var_entry = tk.Entry(win, textvariable=var)`.
3. Looking at `button1 = tk.Button(win,text = '1' ,textvariable = 1)` you are doing something here that does nothing to help. `textvariable = 1` has no purpose here. So lets just delete that. Rewrite that line as `button1 = tk.Button(win, text='1')`
4. Looking at `button1.bind("<Button-1>", handle_button)` is overkill for something the button can handle with the `command` argument. Delete this line entirely and rewrite the `button1` to contain the command. Like this: `button1 = tk.Button(win, text='1', command=handle_button)`
5. Looking at `def window():` we can remove this function and take its content and move it to the global name space. Right now there is no benefit to using a function to set up the GUI so instead lets remove the extra step.

With all that you should have something that looks like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


win = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()

var_entry = tk.Entry(win, textvariable=var)
var_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

def handle_button():
    var.set(4)

tk.Button(win, text='1', command=handle_button).grid(row=2, column=0)

win.mainloop()
```

I am not sure if you have heard of `lambda` just yet but it can be used here to reduce our code just a little bit more. `lambda` is used to create anonymous function and what that means is we can create one line functions that do not require us to define a function by name.

So if we delete the `def handle_button():` function and then we change the `button1` command to a lambda we can save our selves 2 more lines of code that is not really helping us or improving readability.

The new final code should look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


win = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()

var_entry = tk.Entry(win, textvariable=var)
var_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

tk.Button(win, text='1', command=lambda: var.set(4)).grid(row=2, column=0)

win.mainloop()
```

In making all these changes we cut your code in half to achieve the same results and it is a bit cleaner to read.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one and it also worked.

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar()
var_entry = tk.Entry(win,text='var',textvariable=var)
var_entry.grid()

def handle_button(event):
    button_arg = event.widget['text']
    var_entry.insert(0,'end')

button1 = tk.Button(win,text = '1')
button1.bind("<Button-1>", handle_button)
button1.grid()
# similarly I defined all the buttons.


windows()
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

""" Below code restricts the ttk.Entry widget to receive type 'str'. """

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def is_type_int(*args):
  item = var.get()
  try:
    item_type = type(int(item))
    if item_type == type(int(1)):
      print(item)
      print(item_type)
  except:
    ent.delete(0, tk.END)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

var = tk.StringVar()

ent = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
ent.pack(pady=20)

var.trace("w", is_type_int)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).